# How do I create document in Firestore with reliable timestamps?

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

How are any firestore timestamps considered valid coming from the client SDK when they can't be set on the firestore server itself?

Is it not true that an authenticated user could hack his own timestamps?  What is the point of the client sdk offering a timestamp data type if they can't be reliable?  Does that mean we have to use the Firebase Admin sdk to create user data on signup or anything else that requires a timestamp?  What developer doesn't put a timestamp on every collection of data?  If so, what is the point of the client sdk?  Clearly I'm missing something.

i have tried this from the firebase client sdk with no error or timestamp;

```
myFirestoreReference.ref.set({
  userId: firebaseUserCredential.user.uid,
  created: this.$fireStore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

The above code successfully creates the 'userId' but no the 'created' timestamp.

Comment: You have something like 5 questions here.  Could you narrow down your question to a single issue?  This is the convention for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps you could state what you're trying to accomplish, show the code that doesn't work the way you expect, and state what it's doing that's different that your expectation.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Those questions are restatements of the same basic question which is "What is the point of the client sdk if you can't create records with reliable timestamps?"  Can you create a function in a security rule that adds/edits timestamps?

Comment: Doug, thank you for your feedback.  I decided to rename the question to more accurately reflect the issue.

Comment: In the future, ask your questions without the rant, as in "How do I create records with reliable timestamps?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is to use the following code on my server inside an api using the Firebase Admin sdk.  Here is an example of what I was looking for but never found to date.  The code listed below demonstrates the use of...

Firebase Admin sdk => FireStore

It's reliable because it's comes from my server via the Firebase Admin sdk and not the Firebase Client sdk, in addition the serverTimestamp() is set by the FireStore server and not my webserver(via 'new Date()') or the client machine that makes the original request.  I was able to realize this answer by deducing from examples of...

Firebase Client sdk => FireStore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

and

Firebase Admin sdk => Firebase Auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, 
    clientEmail: MY_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: MY_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
  }),
  databaseURL: MY_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});


var serverTimestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()    

admin.firestore().collection('someFireStoreCollection').doc(someFireStoreCollectionId).update({
  someDateField: serverTimestamp
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Successfully updated FireStore");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error updating FireStore:", error);
  throw(error)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the validity of timestamps in security rules.  This rules requires that the client provide the server timestamp token in the `created` field of a document being written to the "foo" collection:

```
match /foo/{id} {
    allow write: if request.resource.data.created == request.time;
}
```

[`request.time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) is the time that the request was received by Firestore, which is also the value implied by the token generated by `serverTimestamp()` on the client.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I hope to use this code, but it implies that you are able to set the serverTimestamp() on the client via the firebase client sdk, which doesn't appear to be the case.  If you are using the to set the serverTimestamp() via the firebase client sdk, please share.

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question to post on Stack Overflow.  [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp) does work, and people do use it.

Comment: The code listed above is a FireStore Security Rule, not the javascript to set the FieldValue.serverTimestamp().  The code snipit above assumes you have already set the timestamp.  My question is how to set the FieldValue.serverTimestamp().  btw the docs do show the FireBASE but not the FireSTORE use of FieldValue.serverTimestamp().  So is this answer part of a FireBASE or FireSTORE implementation?

Comment: OK, that's not how I read your original question at all, nor is it consistent with the comments you left.  If your question is just "how to I create records with server timestamps", then you have a fair amount of editing to do.  Also you should explain exactly what `this.$fireStore` is in your code.  Actually, at this point, I think you're better off asking a whole new question.

Comment: Doug, how does this code account for differences in time due to delays between when the request is made and when it reaches the firestore server?

Comment: It doesn't need to, because `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is just a token that tells the server to generate the timestamp, whenever the request is received.  It's not generated on the client.

Comment: Ok, I see, I wrongly assumed you were doing something like 'new Date()' on the client and some how this code made it secure.  So you are securely setting a date using FieldValue.serverTimestamp() from the Admin sdk from your server and this Firebase Secure Rule is simply reinforcing that.